# Reading out a JSON object in twig

Tags: javascript, json, twig, craftcms

I am trying to get data out of a JSON object but that isn't working quite well.

This is how I made my JSON object (I used `Twig` for this project) and later try to reach it to get the value from it:

```
<script>
    let data = [
        {% for entry in markers %}
        {"name": "{{ entry.title }}", "address": "{{ entry.address.address }}", "lat": "{{ entry.address.lat }}", "lng": "{{ entry.address.lng }}"},
        {% endfor %}
    ];
    let json = JSON.parse(data); //it already goes wrong here.
    alert(json.name);
</script>
```

This is how my object looks:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
address: "Tilburg, Nederland"
lat: "51.56059600"
lng: "5.09191430"
name: "Tilburg"
__proto__: Object
1:
address: "Amsterdam, Nederland"
lat: "52.36798430"
lng: "4.90356140"
name: "Amsterdam"
__proto__: Object
2:
address: "Eindhoven, Nederland"
lat: "51.44164200"
lng: "5.46972250"
name: "eindhoven"
__proto__: Object
3:
address: "Drenthe, Nederland"
lat: "52.94760120"
lng: "6.62305860"
name: "drenthe"
__proto__: Object
4:
address: "Limburg, Nederland"
lat: "51.44272380"
lng: "6.06087260"
name: "limburg"
__proto__: Object
5:
address: "Arnhem, Nederland"
lat: "51.98510340"
lng: "5.89872960"
name: "test"
__proto__: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I think my error is in the part where I make the object. But I don't know what I did wrong.

---

edit: 
I forgot to add the error message. This is what the console tells me in chrome:

> VM9133:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position
>   1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at maps:63 (anonymous) @ maps:63

Comment: `JSON.parse()` isn't be necessary because you render an js-array. Try to remove this line a do an `alert(json[0].name)`. This should give you the name of the first entry.

Comment: @Veve OP is trying to create a valid `JSON` string, not transform a `JSON` string into an object/array

Comment: My bad, sorry, removing my comment and VTC.